# How can I call the most specific method using generics?

Tags: java, type-erasure, generics

Having the following example:

```java
public class Test {

    public static class A {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        m1(a);
    }

    public static <T> void m1(T t) {
        // t.getClass().getSimpleName() is A
        // t instanceof A is true
        m2(t);
    }

    /* Not called */
    public static void m2(A a) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    public static void m2(Object o) {
        // o.getClass().getSimpleName() is A
        // o instanceof A is true
        System.out.println("O");
    }

}
```

I don't understand why `m2(Object o)` is chosen instead of `m2(A a)`. As you can see, when `m2(t)` is called, `t` "is an `A`".

**Output**:

- actual

  ```
  O
  ```
- expected

  ```
  A
  ```

How can I use generics for the situation above so that `m2(A a)` is chosen?

---

***Edit:***

I'd like to have a general solution that will work even if I add a type `B` (similar to `A`).

```java
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    m1(a);
    B b = new B();
    m1(b);
}
...
public static void m2(B b) {
    System.out.println("B");
}
...
```

**Output**:

- actual

  ```
  O
  O
  ```
- expected

  ```
  A
  B
  ```

Comment: The word you're looking for is ["erasure"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: Java generics aren't templates. What you're asking for in the edit is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

You have to do:

```
public static <T extends A> void m1(T t) {
    m2(t);
}
```

Otherwise the compiler cannot infer that the passed parameter is compliant with `m2(A a)` and with pick `m2(Object o)` instead.

Comment: This fixes the specific problem, but I'm looking for a more general solution that allows me to add a `B` (similar to `A`) that doesn't extend `A`. I'll edit my question. It partially solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) which Java does not support. I do not think that generics can help here, but there's the [visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) with which you can emulate it:

```
public class Test {
    public static interface Visitable {
        void accept(Visitor visitor);
    }

    public static class A implements Visitable {
        @Override
        public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
            visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    public static class B implements Visitable {
        @Override
        public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
            visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    public static interface Visitor {
        void visit(A a);

        void visit(B b);
    }

    public static class PrintingVisitor implements Visitor {
        @Override
        public void visit(A a) {
            System.out.println("A");
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(B b) {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Visitable visitable = new A();
        m(visitable);
        visitable = new B();
        m(visitable);
    }

    public static void m(Visitable visitable) {
        visitable.accept(new PrintingVisitor());
    }
}
```